# what is stream type value of video? (isobmff)

Tags: video, types, stream, h.264

Now I am using https://github.com/MPEGGroup/isobmff this repo for isobmff library.
what is stream type value of video? (isobmff)
when i make new Audio sampleDescription,

```
objectTypeIndication = 0x40; /* mpeg-4 audio */
streamType = 0x05; /* audio stream */
decoderBufferSize = 2*6144; /* stereo */
maxBitrate = 128000;
avgBitrate = 128000;

err = MP4NewSampleDescription( trak, sampleEntryH,
        1,
        objectTypeIndication,
        streamType,
        decoderBufferSize,
        maxBitrate,
        avgBitrate,
        decoderSpecificInfoH );

Link : https://github.com/MPEGGroup/isobmff/blob/master/IsoLib/audio_example/src/makeAudioMovieSample.c
```

If i make new video sample description(Avc(h.264)) what values do i input for objectTypeIndication, streamType, decoderBufferSize?

Thank you.